# Using Userway accessibly app, Not reading select box

Tags: html, wai-aria

Im fairly new to ARIA and i am wondering if i have missed something. The widget i am using for a website(UserWay) is not reading my select box so i decided to make one separately to see if i could resolve the issue but i am still having an issue with it reading it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <select id="foo-select" role="listbox"  name="foo">
            <option value="152" aria-labelleadby>Live Oak</option>
            <option value="153" aria-labelledby>Lake City</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
<script data-account="QP61fu7cR3" src="https://cdn.userway.org/widget.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

aria-labelledby is used to point to another element with a text like button or label with text and by its ID(#) and for adding a label to an element use aria-label="test here"

```
<label id="labelID">Lake City </label>

      <select id="foo-select" role="listbox"  name="foo">
                <option value="152" aria-label="Live Oak">Live Oak</option>
                <option value="153" aria-labelledby="labelID">Lake City</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. I did try it but it's still not reading the select box.

Comment: @LoganWeathersby Well not all screen-readers reads everything, even the paid ones miss stuff. Try using ChromeVox and see if that picks up on your elements. Unfortunately web accessibility is not perfect, people create the software and is has to be compatible with markup, browsers etc.